# Keeping Canvas overflow in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a (hopefully) interesting question.

First of all what I'm trying to do here:

I'm trying to create a pie-chart-like set of buttons, later this control will be used within a touch enabled application. The control draws and looks just fine, also all of the behaviours are fine so far. However, one thing that I'm having issues with is the translations I do to all the pieces of the pie.

SO what I do is: I want margin n between the pie pieces, to create this margine I move all pieces away from the middle. This means that the pie piece that's facing UP will have a negative translation. This in turn means that the Canvas will clip a part of the top (due the top being at 14, -2 for example). Another thing that I've added are pieces of text which are also making the pie pieces quite a bit longer. See the image included for reference.

[image](http://www.badguy.nl/images/CanvasIssue.png)

To the left you can see the clipping issue I'm talking about to the right you can see an arbitrarily translated version of the same thing.

Some code paste:

Main window XAML:

```
<controls:PieMenu Radius="100" Padding="10">
<controls:PieMenu.MenuItems>
    <controls:PieMenuItem Text="Employment" Brush="#FF33FF" Command="BrowseBack" />
    <controls:PieMenuItem Text="General" Brush="#9933FF" Command="BrowseBack" />
    <controls:PieMenuItem Text="Internships" Brush="#3333FF" Command="BrowseBack" />
    <controls:PieMenuItem Text="Bla" Brush="#3399FF" Command="BrowseBack" />
    <controls:PieMenuItem Text="Bla" Brush="#007AF5" Command="BrowseBack" />
</controls:PieMenu.MenuItems>
```

PieMenu XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PieControlLibrary.PieMenu"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:self="clr-namespace:PieControlLibrary"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- <CollectionViewSource x:Name="menuItemCollectionViewSource" Source="{Binding MenuItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=self:PieMenu}}"/>-->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}" x:Key="listViewStyle">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <self:PieButton Radius="{Binding Radius, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=self:PieMenu}}" 
                                    Degrees="{Binding Degrees, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=self:PieMenu}}"
                                    Brush="{Binding Brush}"
                                    Command="{Binding Command}" 
                                    Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="menuItemsView" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=self:PieMenu}}" Style="{StaticResource listViewStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

PieButton (this is what the pie menu items are converted to)

```
<UserControl x:Class="PieControlLibrary.PieButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:control="clr-namespace:PieControlLibrary"
         xmlns:TextOnPath="clr-namespace:Petzold.TextOnPath"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         >
<Grid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=control:PieButton}}" Command="{Binding Command}">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Canvas >
                    <Path Data="{Binding PathData}" Fill="{Binding Brush}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextOnPath:TextOnPathControl PathFigure="{Binding TextPath}" Text="{Binding Text}" FontFamily="Consolas" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" FontStretch="Normal" />
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but when you draw your pie chart, just leave some extra space around the edges so you can move the pie pieces out from the center?

Comment: I am leaving extra space, the major issue is that I do not know how much extra space to add. So if anyone has some ways on measuring the size of text or any visual elements (or combinations of elements) I'd love to know how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a `RenderTransform` when your pie pieces expand to shift or scale the image a tiny bit to keep it in bounds?

Comment: Sorry about  the late reply  (I was on holiday for two weeks), the main issue that I have with this solution is that I do not know by how much it has resized, and on top of that the size of the text displayed around it is variable as well. So for any of the suggestions to work I need to know exactly how big everything is.

Comment: There is an ActualHeight and ActualWidth property which I've used in the past when the size of an object changes during runtime. Perhaps you can use that somehow?

Comment: Hi Rachel, I've tried using these the problem however is that the text scales. However it is programmed to scale down (from 100 pt) for some reason the actual height is around the height you'd expect for a 100 pt font. Or let me put it this way: it was painfully clear that the font ActualHeight (compared to the slice which i knew was a certain size) property was nowhere near what should be the height by visual comparison.